# How to click a button from parent page in pop-up child window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to click a button in parent page from pop-up child window. The parent page uses a master page while the child window doesn't. My code works whenever the parent page has no master page but when there is it didn't.

Below is my code.

```
function clickParent()
{
  document.getElementById('<%=btnclick.ClientID %>').click();
}

function callClick()
{
  window.opener.clickParent();
}
```

I call the callClick() function in child page button like this..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.[GetType](), "parentRel", "clickParent();", True)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.opener.location.href=''` try this

Comment: @RajeevMehta...Then what will I put inside the ' '?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when we add master page all the id will be contactinated with some additional string .
To avoid this add attribute ClientIdMode="Static" to all the asp controls.
Eg:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```